# Badge Suggestion: Leader

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request

Where users have greater than 20 answers with score of 8 or better and the total number of answers they have given is 2x or 3x the number of total questions they've asked.

Of course sometimes a question is more valuable than hundreds of answers, but still I think promoting a ratio where users are giving more to the community than they take away is good.

Yeah?  What do you think?

**Edit**
Maybe a simpler way to do this is to award the badge when you have 2x or 3x the number of Nice Answer badges as Nice Question badges.

It's true there's plenty of incentive out there obviously, or we all wouldn't be here...  But I think the idea with badges is to tend toward a more continuous, equal rewarding of every different class of contributor

**Edit 2**
Coming Next Year:  badges based on badges based on badges.

Twenty years from now the release notes for version 34123412341234 will have only one item:

- FRACTAL BADGES

Comment: Yah maybe the rep requirement is weak - a bronze then?

Comment: This badge would require a division by zero in my case. I could bring down the entire Stack Exchange network! I approve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've got 20 x 8 score answers they've given you 1600 rep already, plus you've got a good chance of many of those answers being voted up further to +10 so you could end with a dozen or more 'Nice Answer' badges too. Isn't that enough already ? Seems like this would giving another badge to users with lots of rep/badges already for something there's already a lot of incentive to do.

Comment: Yes, I see this as really just a badge for getting other badges.